# Expresso Store add text area for customer to add details per product

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, checkout

How can I add a text area to product so a customer can add some content to submit with the order.  Ideally  only on certain products.  Kind of like if you want to have a product engraved the customer could add a message in the add to cart form.

It would be nice to have this product dynamic so it doesn't appear on all products.

Answer (score 0):

If the text area is attached to the order as a whole, use [Custom Order fields](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#custom_order_fields).

If the text area is attached to individual products, use a [custom modifier](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#input_custom_modifier_name_name) or [modifier built into the product](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#modifiers_variable_pair).